# VBA - Select text in Outlook email body

Tags: vba, excel

Below is an image:

[image]

Currently, I have the following code:

```
Sub Mail()
    Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks("book1"): Set sh = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim msgbody As String

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "subjsect"
        .Body = "somerandomtexthererhejoiehtjejheirjgoejrgijewr+goehjpogerhgeirog stackoverflow"
        .Display 
    End With
    Set weditor = OutApp.ActiveInspector.wordEditor
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I believe that the key-line is

```
    Set weditor = OutApp.ActiveInspector.wordEditor
```

because it enables me (I think) to manipulate the body as if it were in Word. I just can't get it to search and select the text I want to be selected (such as stackoverflow in the image above).

Answer (score 0):

To get the currently open item in your Outlook, all you need is:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim msgbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
msgbody = OutMail.Body
' if you want to edit the body - OutMail.Body = "BOB" for example!
' search and editing code goes here...

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```